# importing xls file in matlab

Tags: matlab, importerror

In `matlab7.0.1` I am trying to get data from xls file which contains text

```
D=3Dxlsread('myfile.xls')
```

it gives me the error: `Error: Missing variable or function.`

Comment: There is no `3Dxlsread` function in matlab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
[ndata, text, alldata] = xlsread('myExample.xlsx')
```

See documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html#bthgbmn).